# Android - Way to set the page to scroll if it doesn't fit?

Tags: android, scroll

One of my screen has button which won't display on screen below a certain width. Is there a way to allow the screen to scroll if this is the case so the buttons can be got to?

Comment: Put everything inside scrollview.

Comment: I am currently using a relativelayout

Comment: I think I got it though!

Comment: Awesome! Yeah, if it wasn't clear ... you want to embed your outermost layout element (a RelativeLayout in your case) within a ScrollView element, making the ScrollView your outermost layout element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, embed your layout within a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Comment: How exactly would you do this? I already have my buttons and layout. Is there a simple way?

Comment: Here's a decent tutorial [ScrollView’s handy trick](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)

Comment: @newbyca - thanks for the link - nb for markdown syntax the text is in square brackets and the url is angle brackets

Answer (score 2):

Simply wrap your layout in a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Comment: In case if we want to keep a view attached to Bottom the scroll will work but the button won't be attached