# Activity doesn't stretch when adding elements

Tags: android, layout

Im adding other layout to my current layout like this:

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.average_layout_salaryListContainer);
            for (String month : mVacation.getMonthNameList()) {
                LinearLayout childElement = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.salary_list_element, null);
                TextView monthTextView = (TextView) childElement.findViewById(R.id.salary_list_element_textView_month);
                monthTextView.setText(month);
                parent.addView(childElement);
            }
```

While I have a lot of month (12 or more) some of added elements are invisible, but I can't scroll down. How to avoid this?

Comment: in your XML does your linear layout wrap content? Also is it inside a scroll view?

Answer (score 5):

You should put your main layout inside a `ScrollView` that way you will be able to scroll down when stuff gets too long
more info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Answer (score 5):

You should wrap your entire layout inside a `ScrollView` that way your layout should fit nicely and scroll when necesary.You should take a further look here : [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your parent LinearLayout view with a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). Check out this post:
[Android - Way to set the page to scroll if it doesn't fit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272580/android-way-to-set-the-page-to-scroll-if-it-doesnt-fit)